# addGroupMember define member name

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to add a member full name? now I see only:

```
var member = {
email: userEmail,
role: 'MEMBER'};
```

and if I try to add member name like this:

```
var member = {
email: userEmail,
name: {
  givenName: 'name',
  familyName: 'name'
},
role: 'MEMBER'};
```

I dont see it has any affect on the added member properties

is it recommended to add a user instead? what would be the different properties between a user and a member?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the documentation, the Directory API stores users and can assign them, i.e. existing users, to groups.

To add a user and assign them to a group requires two calls:

(1) Add a new user by

```
function addUser() {
  var user = {
    primaryEmail: 'liz@example.com',
    name: {
      givenName: 'Elizabeth',
      familyName: 'Smith'
    },
    // Generate a random password string.
    password: Math.random().toString(36)
  };
  user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
  Logger.log('User %s created with ID %s.', user.primaryEmail, user.id);
}
```

Here you can specify the name in further detail. The crucial API call here is `AdminDirectory,Users.insert(). [Its documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert) details the object that you can pass to describe a user.

(2) Add this member to a group

```
function addGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = 'liz@example.com';
  var groupEmail = 'bookclub@example.com';
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

The crucial API call here is `AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail)`. As you can see from [its documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert), it takes a [Members Resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members#resource), which does not take the name property.

Comment: Thanks. only thing I havent figured out yet is how you define the AdminDirectory.Users.insert method with the specific domain to which you want to add the user to...or is it automatically based on the API project authorization which I gave in advance to my specific domain?